# BOINC Says No Disk Space

Tags: 16.04, boinc

I am suddenly experiencing a **no disk space** problem with BOINC on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not too well acquainted with Linux yet so I'm having trouble figuring out why.

In BOINC preferences I am allowing 100 GB disk space usage and only 9 GB is being used according to the /var/lib/boinc-client folder properties.

Here are some outputs:

```
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:04 AM PDT |  | Starting BOINC client version 7.6.31 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:04 AM PDT |  | log flags: file_xfer, sched_ops, task
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:04 AM PDT |  | Libraries: libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:04 AM PDT |  | Data directory: /var/lib/boinc-client
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | CUDA: NVIDIA GPU 0: GeForce GTX 960 (driver version 361.45, CUDA version 8.0, compute capability 5.2, 2047MB, 1956MB available, 2541 GFLOPS peak)
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | OpenCL: NVIDIA GPU 0: GeForce GTX 960 (driver version 361.45.18, device version OpenCL 1.2 CUDA, 2047MB, 1956MB available, 2541 GFLOPS peak)
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Host name: ProLiant-Generic
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Processor: 16 GenuineIntel Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz [Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5]
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Processor features: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | OS: Linux: 4.4.0-36-generic
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Memory: 17.63 GB physical, 17.99 GB virtual
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Disk: 257.14 GB total, 98.73 GB free
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Local time is UTC -7 hours
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Config: GUI RPCs allowed from:
```

SNIP due to too many links

```
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Host location: none
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | General prefs: using your defaults
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Reading preferences override file
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | Preferences:
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | max memory usage when active: 14439.98MB
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:13 AM PDT |  | max memory usage when idle: 17147.47MB
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:18 AM PDT |  | max disk usage: 100.00GB
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:18 AM PDT |  | max CPUs used: 15
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:40:18 AM PDT |  | (to change preferences, visit a project web site or select Preferences in the Manager)
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:43:33 AM PDT | Poem@Home | Requesting new tasks for NVIDIA GPU
Tue 30 Aug 2016 09:43:37 AM PDT | Poem@Home | Scheduler request completed: got 0 new tasks
```

SNIP due to verbosity

```
Tue 30 Aug 2016 11:01:31 AM PDT | climateprediction | No tasks sent
Tue 30 Aug 2016 11:01:31 AM PDT | climateprediction.net | Message from server: Weather At Home 2 (wah2) needs 1907.35MB more disk space.  You currently have 0.00 MB available and it needs 1907.35 MB.
```

```
owner@ProLiant-Generic:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.8G     0  8.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G  9.7M  1.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       258G  146G   99G  60% /
tmpfs           8.9G  216K  8.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           8.9G     0  8.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1.8G   60K  1.8G   1% /run/user/1000
owner@ProLiant-Generic:~$
```

```
owner@ProLiant-Generic:~$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            2305619    609  2305010    1% /dev
tmpfs           2310396    870  2309526    1% /run
/dev/sda1      17129472 399936 16729536    3% /
tmpfs           2310396      9  2310387    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2310396      6  2310390    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2310396     18  2310378    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           2310396     14  2310382    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           2310396     31  2310365    1% /run/user/1000
owner@ProLiant-Generic:~$
```

Comment: How are we supposed to read this? Please edit or repost. Cheers, Al

Comment: Sorry about that, Al. I wasn't paying attention. It formated itself okay on the GPUGrid boards but I didn't get a reply yet.

Comment: You're welcome, @SolarSurfer! :-) Anyway, it seems that @edwinksl is a much better editor than me. :-) I should learn!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out how to fix the problem, though I don't know if I fully understand why it occurred, or rather why I was unable to get accurate information to diagnose it.

It turned out that the climateprediction.net folder in my BOINC folder was full of 100 + GB of old and crashed work units. That was preventing downloads of any other project's tasks too. I didn't relish the prospect of hunting down the active work units in that bunch and saving them, so I just reset the project and now everything is working again.

I had originally opened Nautilus from Cairo-Dock, right-clicked on the BOINC folder and chosen properties. That informed me that there was 9 GB used and 100 + GB free space. However, when I thought to open Nautilus using 'gksudo nautilus' in a terminal I got different results and was able to pinpoint the problem. I don't understand why it should make any difference but it seemed that it did.

I should add, in my own defense, that I spent Sunday night in the ER of a local hospital and had only got one or two hours sleep - and I still haven't caught up yet.

Cheers!

Comment: Well, even if you don't have an explication yet, the important fact is that you have solved your problem. In this case then, I think that you should mark your own answer as the solution, so that your question could be classified as being solved. Thus, other people who encounter the same problem as yours will be able to find the answer more rapidly and easier. If I am correct, in order to do that, you'll have to wait for a day or two. (Meanwhile, other answers are supposed to come.) So, do come back! Regards!

Comment: Will mark it after 18 hrs have elapsed @Cristiana, since apparently them's the rules :-)

Comment: Also,  thank you @edwinksl, for the nice edit. I tried to thank you yesterday but the 'add comment' button wouldn't cooperate.